# Moment js Not returning the right day of the week

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to use Momentjs to return the day of the week (ex. "monday" or "mon", doesn't matter as long as it's the name of the day of the week) for the string number that I stored in the db (ex `"3"`). For some reason I keep getting Monday returned.

```
var values = ["3", "06:00", "18:00"];
moment().isoWeekday(values[0]).format('ddd');
//returns "Mon"
```

I've also tried using `moment('3','d').format('ddd')`

I've also tried using `moment().days('3').format('ddd')`

Always returns the same day. Usually Sat or Mon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
moment().isoWeekday(parseInt(values[0])).format('ddd');
```

And in general, store the week day as integer and not string:

```
var values = [3, "06:00", "18:00"];
```